# React redux const function being reached but then immediately returns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Beginner at this.

I have added code that should go to the API and retrieve a data object that I can later load into local storage. I have added it and it is reached but then it immediately returns before performing any of the functionality.

Here is the entire file. I have the actions with the reducer for the moment but will move the actions to another file later.

```
import { fetch, addTask } from 'domain-task'
import { saveJwt, clearJwt } from '../auth/jwt'
import { handleErrors } from '../utils/http'
//import {requestSelectData} from '../selectData/reducer'

const REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN = 'REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN'
const RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN = 'RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN'
const ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN = 'ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN'

const REQUEST_SELECT_DATA = 'REQUEST_SELECT_DATA'
const RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA = 'RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA'
const ERROR_SELECT_DATA = 'ERROR_SELECT_DATA'

const REQUEST_USER = 'REQUEST_USER'
const RECEIVE_USER = 'RECEIVE_USER'
const ERROR_USER = 'ERROR_USER'

// ******************* action
export const requestLoginToken = (username, password) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: username })

    const payload = {
      userName: username,
      password: password,
    }

    const task = fetch('/api/jwt', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
    })
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: data })
        saveJwt(data)

        selectData()

      })
      .catch(error => {
        clearJwt()
        dispatch({ type: ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: error.message })
      })
    addTask(task)
    return task
  }

const selectData = () => 
  (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })

  const token = jwt.access_token
  const headers = new Headers({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  })
  const selectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
  })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: data })
        .catch(error => {
          clearJwt()
          dispatch({ type: ERROR_SELECT_DATA, payload: error.message })
        })
    })
}

export const requestUser = (jwt) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_USER, payload: jwt })

    const token = jwt.access_token
    const headers = new Headers({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    })
    const task = fetch('/api/jwt/user', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers,
    })
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_USER, payload: data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        clearJwt()
        dispatch({ type: ERROR_USER, payload: error.message })
      })
    addTask(task)
    return task
  }

// ******************* reducer
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  isAuthorised: false,
  username: null,
  jwt: null,
  locations: null,
  states: null,
  CompanyStateShortName: null,
  error: null,
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        isAuthorised: false,
        username: action.payload,
        jwt: null,
        error: null,
      }
    case RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isAuthorised: true,
        jwt: action.payload,
        error: null,
      }
    case ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isAuthorised: false,
        username: null,
        jwt: null,
        error: action.payload,
      }

    case REQUEST_SELECT_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        isAuthorised: false,
        jwt: action.payload,
        locations: null,
        states: null,
        CompanyStateShortName: null,
        error: null,
      }

    case RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isAuthorised: true,
        locations: action.payload.locations,
        states: action.payload.states,
        CompanyStateShortName: action.payload.CompanyStateShortName
      }
    case ERROR_SELECT_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        locations: null,
        states: null,
        CompanyStateShortName: null,
        error: action.payload,
      }

    case REQUEST_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        isAuthorised: false,
        jwt: action.payload,
        username: null,
        error: null,
      }
    case RECEIVE_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isAuthorised: true,
        username: action.payload.username,
        error: null,
      }
    case ERROR_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isAuthorised: false,
        username: null,
        jwt: null,
        error: action.payload,
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I added the const "selectData".

```
const selectData = () => 
  (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })

  const token = jwt.access_token
  const headers = new Headers({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  })
  const selectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
  })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: data })
        .catch(error => {
          clearJwt()
          dispatch({ type: ERROR_SELECT_DATA, payload: error.message })
        })
    })
}
```

It simply gets to this line and returns and I dont know why?

```
    const selectData = () => 
  (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })
```

Why isnt it going through the entire function? ..and I am not getting any errors.

Comment: I am not sure but react can dispatch redux action only once per function call, because dispatch simply means return {...}

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is asynchronous.  It starts the process and then immediately returns.  At some point in the future *if and when the network access succeeds*, the code in the `then()` will be invoked.

My guess, the access is failing, so that code never runs.  Check your server or the browser's network log.

Also, why on Earth are assigning the return value of the fetch to a constant with the same name as the enclosing function?  It happens not to break anything, but simply returning it would be much better.

Comment: selectData is only called once the previous fetch has succeeded - it has gone off and saved the JWT to local storage. I tried changing the name of the const that was the fetch with no success.

Comment: The name doesn't matter to the computer.  Since the enclosing function ends immediately after the assignment, it's meaningless.  Indeed, some linters will flag it with a warning.